# Can scp setup file mode of copied files?

Tags: file-permissions, scp

The man page of `scp` does not mention any [mode](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix)) option. Is there a way (or other program) that could setup the mode for transferred files?

Comment: What do you mean by setup the file modes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rsync` has a `--chmod` argument, which sounds like what you are looking for.